# After changing the parent of a child window with SetParent, the child window still sends notification to the old parent

Tags: c++, winapi

I've created a dialog window in VC2012 with some edits and other components. I then created a custom component that works as a grouping for any child window, so I set the parent of every component in the dialog with SetParent passing the grouping custom control. That works fine, but then I noticed that the Edit controls still send notifications to the older parent window. how to fix this?

Comment: Many controls cache the original parent. Not much you can do about it.

Comment: I guess I would have to forward the message on my own. I was about to view the video that by coincidence you posted in this link to see if I could get a way around using windows. http://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/scobleizer/raymond-chen-pdc-05-talk-five-things-every-win32-programmer-needs-to-know