# Edit control doesn't generate WM_COMMAND messages

Tags: winapi, controls, editcontrol

I have an edit control. In the parent window I'm listening a `WM_COMMAND` message. But my control doesn't send it on change. Moreover, when I'm watching messages with Spy I can see only different keyboard messages on the edit control itself and the only message in the main parent window is `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT`.

P.S.: The only interesting thing I'm doing - I'm creating an edit with `HWND_MESSAGE` parent and assign a parent later with `SetParent();`

Comment: Why are you making a message only window be the parent? Did you explore what happens if you don't do that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan In the beginning I don't know the parent of the control - it's created dynamically. Later I'm setting a parent and even changing a parent during runtime. Creating control with a parent behaves well, i.e. everything works as expected.

Comment: Yep, digging more deeply I found an [article](https://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;EN-US;Q104069). That's weird (.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an edit control, notifications are sent to the original parent of the control. That is, in your case, the message only window.

In a comment to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22916895/after-changing-the-parent-of-a-child-window-with-setparent-the-child-window-sti) Raymond Chen says:

> Many controls cache the original parent. Not much you can do about it.

You may be best postponing creation of the edit control until you have created its parent.

Comment: Thanks. The weirdest thing is that for the most controls it works ok, but I have to change a code for consistency.

Comment: I dug out a dupe question here with a comment from Raymond that confirms it all.